# Laravel - как правильно отсортировать или отобразить модель

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, сортировка

Например в модели есть поля `id`, `name`, `status`.
В таблице внесены такие данные как
id name status
1  Anna Open
2  Bob  Closed
3. John Reopen
4. Patrick Open
Мне нужно отобразить в блейде сначала ребят со статусом Open, а потом уже клоуз и реоупен. Если делать `Model::orderBy('status')->get();` то выходит не то что нужно, подскажите как правильно реализовать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можете сделать группировку с помощью коллекции. Например:

```
Model::all()->groupBy('status');
```

В результате вернется коллекция состоящих из 3 массивов (в данном случае) каждый из которых можете выводить в любом удобном месте! Ключи коллекции соответственно будут названия статуса. Т.е. Вы спокойно можете получить `$model['Open']....` и т.д и далее перебрать данные.

Comment: Я думал об этом да, но мне бы хотелось сразу пройти 1 форычем и получить нужную последовательность данных... а так я понимая мне нужно на каждый статус делать отдельный перебор или внутри перебора проверять статус не очень удобно...

Comment: @Domilola тогда не понятно что Вы хотите сделать и на выходе получить, покажите нужный вид и тот который сейчас получается

Comment: @Domilola Вы можете "склеить" эти массивы с помощью `array_merge` и тогда нужно будет перебрать только 1 массив. Если вас именно перебор нескольких не устраивает

Comment: Типо первый сделать Model::where('status','Open')->get(); а второй Model::whereNot('status,'Open')->get(); а потом их склеить ?

Comment: @Domilola Или так или как предложил Дмитрий - достать сгруппированные коллекции и потом смержить их в нужном порядке в 1 массив